# Subpartitioning several partitions in a table

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

I came here to find solutions a lot of times and almost always I found some response that fit perfect for me. And now I finally decided to write my first question.

Is also my first time that I have to mount a db with partitioning but not so simple partitioning, that is why I didn't found any solution in mysql official documentation.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE SystemEvents 
(
    ID int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    ReceivedAt datetime NULL,
    DeviceReportedTime datetime NULL,
    Facility smallint NULL,
    Priority smallint NULL,
    FromHost varchar(60) NULL,
    Message text,
    NTSeverity int NULL,
    EventSource varchar(60),
    EventUser varchar(60) NULL,
    EventCategory int NULL,
    EventID int NULL,
    InfoUnitID int NULL ,
    SysLogTag varchar(60),
    EventLogType varchar(60),
)
```

And I need to make partitions by "FromHost" key:

```
PARTITIOM BY LIST (FromHost)
(
   PARTITION p01 VALUES IN ('server1'),
   PARTITION p02 VALUES IN ('server2'),
   PARTITION p03 VALUES IN ('server3', 'server4'),
   PARTITION p04 VALUES IN less than maxvalue
);
```

Until here it's all OK. But here comes the difficult part:

Once the main table is partitioned into several servers, I need to separate the content of every partition into subpartitions by date field (receivedAt), week if it is posible.

The reason is, that the database has to store the events of all servers in the company an entire year, and both "server1" and "server2" creates near 3 millons rows every month. The most of the queries we use to need are first by server and then, once we have the the list of events filtered for the choosen server, we search by date, to find the event we are looking for.

So, can you indicate me how would be the script to create subpartitons into partition p01 and p02, sorted by receivedAt field?

If there are something that is not understood, please tell me and I will rephrase it.

Thanks a lot.

Regards.
Xavidpr

Answer (score 0):

All columns used for partitioning have to be part of the primary key if the table has a primary key.

Secondly you want to partition on FromHost which is a varchar column. Using varchar limits the types of partitioning you can use. Besides, if the table is large enough to warrant partitions, it is a good idea to use a numeric id for the host instead of the host name. This will speed up things and also reduce the table size.

A straight forward solution would be this:

Use `RANGE` partitioning for partitioing on DateTime.
Use KEY or HASH partitioning for partitioning on Host (preferably an integer host_id)

Since you cannot use `RANGE` on subpartitions, you will have to partition by `RANGE` and sub partition by `KEY` or `HASH`

In other words partition by `ReceivedAt` and subpartition by `FromHost`